# Rails execute script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I am building a script in on of my controllers to fill a database with an excel files data. I would build the function, then access it through a route. (That i guess i can protect with cancan) But i thought about it, and it doesn't seem very ... 'Railsy'.

I know the scripts folder exists, and it is *probably* for these kinds of tasks. I've tried googling stuff like 'rails execute script' and other stuff, but i can't find any good advice for what to do next.

I'm sorry if this seems kind of stupid, but in my apps i've been kind of hacking around stuff to make it work, so any advice on this task would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean a shell script, ruby script, or...?

Comment: @DaveNewton a shell script is in bash right? I would write it in ruby if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

If you need to upload the file in the app and process it, it should probably go in the "lib"directory and be accessed like any other Ruby library/module/etc.

If it's something you need to run locally, "on demand", "scripts" is fine. If you need access to your rails environment when running it like any Rails models, you can run it from "rails console" or "rails runner".

As Aln said, there are a variety of ways it could be scheduled as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'

# regular ruby code here
```

and have it running just like any other util. Of course you can always call any *.rb with simply

```
ruby somescript.rb
```

If you need some scheduled script, check into [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem.